# How to set a column value of mysql database as another column value using parameters in vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I need to send an update query to mysql like the following:

```
UPDATE myTableName SET OldField = NewField, NewField = 'New Value'
WHERE myFieldName = 'myFieldValue'
```

I need to store the old value of the field "NewField" in the field "OldField" when updating but I also need to update using parameters.

The problem is that I don't know how to send "NewField" (as name of a field) as a parameter like in the following function:

```
Public Function DBUpdate(ByVal connectionString As String, ByVal Tbl As String, ByVal FldsNValues As Dictionary(Of String, String), Optional ByVal Whe As String = "") As Boolean
    Dim iReturn As Boolean
    Using SQLConnection As New MySqlConnection(connectionString)
        Using sqlCommand As New MySqlCommand()
            Dim CmdTxt$ = "UPDATE " & Tbl & " SET "
            For Each k In FldsNValues.Keys
                CmdTxt &= k & " = @" & k & ", "
            Next
            CmdTxt = CmdTxt.Substring(0, CmdTxt.Length - 2)
            If Whe <> "" Then
                CmdTxt &= " WHERE " & Whe
            End If
            With sqlCommand
                .CommandText = CmdTxt
                .Connection = SQLConnection
                .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                For Each k In FldsNValues.Keys
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@" & k, FldsNValues(k))
                Next
            End With
            Try
                SQLConnection.Open()
                sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
                iReturn = True
            Catch ex As MySqlException
                MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString)
                iReturn = False
            Finally
                SQLConnection.Close()
            End Try
        End Using
    End Using
    Return iReturn
End Function
```

How can I set a Field Name as parameter?

Is it possible?

This is an example of what I want:

```
TABLE "Baby" RECORD BEFORE UPDATE

Fld_Id | Fld_Name | Fld_OldValue | Fld_NewValue
   1   |   Sally  | 12 years old | 14 years old
```

Then I update with:

```
UPDATE Baby SET Fld_OldValue = Fld_NewValue, Fld_NewValue = '15 years old'
WHERE Fld_Name = 'Sally'
```

So, after udate:

```
TABLE "Baby" RECORD AFTER UPDATE

Fld_Id | Fld_Name | Fld_OldValue | Fld_NewValue
   1   |   Sally  | 14 years old | 15 years old
```

I would like to do this using the function above (so I can use it for all my update queries)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I think I get what you're asking now. Hopefully the third time's the charm.

It seems the problem is that you're trying to parameterize `SET Fld_OldValue = Fld_NewValue`, but are unable to pass the *column* `Fld_NewValue` as a parameter. (Instead, your function is probably passing the *string* "Fld_NewValue".)

Unfortunately, you can't do what you want the way you are trying to do it. Parameters are, by definition, a column and a *value*. They are part of the VB.NET sqlControl class that pass *data* along with your SQL command, but they **cannot** pass SQL instructions themselves. (In fact, this behavior is one of the primary reasons to use parameters, because this is how parameterization prevents SQL injection in strings.)

The good news is that there's always a way to get the result you're looking for if you're willing to work around such issues. I can think of two ways make your function work as intended:

**1) Write a secondary function that returns the correct value for each field.**

This function should (1) determine if the "value" stored in your dictionary is truly a value or is in fact a column name, (2) perform a query to get the value stored in the appropriate column when passed a column name, and (3) return the appropriate value. You can then use this function in the function above to make sure the correct values are set.

**2) Use non-parameterized SQL for the columns in question.**

This will require a significant rewrite of your function, because the syntax `SET k = @k` will not always be correct. You will have to add each command (and, if appropriate, parameter) individually in the same loop. Something like:

```
.CommandText &= k & " = "
If isColumn(k) Then    'You must determine how to evaluate this yourself
    .CommandText &= FldsNValues(k)
Else
    .CommandText &= "@" & k
    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@" & k, FldsNValues(k))
End If
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but (I think it was my fault) the field name that I need to set as value is "NewField". I have no problems with "Where". I need to store the old value of the field "NewField" in the field "OldField" to compare them when I need it.

Comment: @genespos, Could you clarify why you think you need to use parameters for this? Copying data from one column to another doesn't require any input values; all the data resides in the mySQL database, not in your VB code. Is the issue doing this for each of the dictionary KVP's you're looping through?

Comment: It's exactly my problem! I would like to use the function I wrote even if the value I need to pass is a field name. Is it possible? I need to pass a parameter not as value but as field name.

Comment: @genespos, as I began my original answer by clarifying, there is a difference between a variable in VB and a parameter in SQL. Strictly speaking, parameters are only used for *values*. However, I think what you want can be easily accomplished. I've edited my answer with a basic approach; if this doesn't answer your question, could you give an example of your table structure?

Comment: I edited my question adding an example. I hope it's clear now

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. Finally I choose to write another function to accomplish this particular need adding as non parametrized the "field copy". Bye